# How to find number of days left from now to an epoch time in grafana elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, dashboard

Example: I want to find number of days left from now (1576477782) to August 22, 2020 7:39:13 AM (1598062153) which is **249 days, 19 hours, 39 minutes and 31 seconds**. How this can be done in grafana with Elasticsearch as datasource. I can get "1598062153" as a value of a metric in ES.

Comment: take a look at the datediff functions of elastic https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-datetime.html

Comment: This will not work for epoch-time will it?

Answer (score -1):

This can be resolved by doing **1576477782 - (new Date().getTime() / 1000)**

The (new Date().getTime() / 1000)--- this will give current date in Epoch Seconds